# Excel: Keep cell containing date the same after being set, without macros

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016, date

I have a table that looks like this:

[image: Table]

What I want to achieve is that when you fill in a row (other than the 'Time' section), the 'Time' column automatically fills itself in. Then, it stays the same forever, regardless of how the table is altered. What I have now is:

`=IF(E3="", IF(COUNTBLANK(A2:D2)=0, NOW(), ""), E2)`

This works to some extent, in that it sets the date when you finish filling in a row, and the date does not change; however, on the last row of the table the date will still change, until a new last row is created. However, I need the dates to stay exactly the same as right after their row is filled in.

I've tried adding helper columns and `SUMPRODUCT` to track what to update and when, and what to keep the same, but nothing worked; therefore, I reverted to the above formula that *mostly* works, other than on the last row (as aforementioned).

Please let me know if you have any ideas. As the title suggests, I cannot use macros.

Comment: I think you are going to be limited to choosing between entering the date/time manually, or using VBA.

Comment: If you don't want to use macro to get the result, try to use shortcut key enter time manually: ctrl+shift+；

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Since you have restricted the scope of the solution to Non-VBA in that case I would like to suggest a little tricky solution.**

**How it works:**

*- Before you enter the Formula Click,,*

- **File, Option** then **Formula** and **Check the Enable Iterative Calculation** and set **Maximum iteration Value to 1000**.
- Finish with **Ok**
- Set Appropriate **Time Format** for requited Data Range.

*Write this Formula in Cell `E1` and Fill down.*

```
=IF(COUNTBLANK(A1:D1)<>0,"",IF(E1="",NOW(),E1))
```

**Note,** the Time will remain unchanged unless you will not delete any value and renter new one in cell/cells. *(Time will remain unchanged in case of modification).*

Comment: I added a helper column with `=IF(COUNTBLANK(A1:D1)=0, TRUE, IF(F1="", FALSE, F1))`, and that handles deletion of values as well.

Comment: @GezaKerecsenyi,, glad to help you keep asking ☺